# HTTP Post to Ebay Trading API using Curl

Tags: http, post, curl, ebay-api

I am attempting to do a `HTTP POST` to retrieve order data from Ebays Trading API.  I am somewhat new to this - as you may see. I first used their API Test Tool and was successful getting my actual order data via the Production environment.

I copied the HTTP header info and XML Requestion section, put that in a file, along with what I thought would make it a valid HTTP Post, and then used the Curl executable - called via a batch file.

This did not work - so I changed to a simpler request - GeteBayTime - and got the exact same results.

My batch file is ... (all one line)

```
Curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:text/xml" -d @postfile https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll  > out.xml
```

The postfile is ...

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll
User-Agent: App v1.0
Connection: Keep Alive
Content-Length: 125
Content-Type: text/xml
X-EBAY-API-APP-ID:***-MyReal-APP-ID-here***
X-EBAY-API-VERSION:807  
X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL:707
X-EBAY-API-SITE-ID:0
X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME:GeteBayTime
X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING:XML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GeteBayTimeRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
</GeteBayTimeRequest>
```

And the result (in out.xml) is ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<GeteBayOfficialTimeResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<Timestamp>2013-02-04 02:56:43</Timestamp><Ack>Failure</Ack>-<Errors>  
<ShortMessage>Unsupported API call.</ShortMessage><LongMessage>The API call 
"GeteBayOfficialTime" is invalid or not supported in this release.</LongMessage>   
<ErrorCode>2</ErrorCode><SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
<ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification></Errors><Build>15743293</Build>
</GeteBayOfficialTimeResponse
```

Can anyone spot my problem(s) ??

Answer (score 1):

only request body must be in data -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GeteBayTimeRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
</GeteBayTimeRequest>
```

this values must be in header -

```
X-EBAY-API-APP-ID:***-MyReal-APP-ID-here***
X-EBAY-API-VERSION:807  
X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL:707
X-EBAY-API-SITE-ID:0
X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME:GeteBayTime
X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING:XML
```

Comment: I tried that (I think ... see below) and got the exact same result.  I changed "postfile" to be ONLY what you show above ("this values must be in the header" - with my correct APP-ID - NO OTHER CHANGE) followed by one blank line followed by what you wrote first ("only request body must be in data") and used the same call to the curl executable.  Again, my "postfile" includes only what you show above with my correct APP-ID.  Same results.

Comment: I have now gotten the Curl command line exe to post to the ebay production site and return the expected order data.  I will attempt to document how I did this and answer my own question.  I assume I should use the link below ... "Answer your question" ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution - I spend some time to find the right way:

```
Curl -X POST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -H "X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL:911" -H "X-EBAY-API-SITEID:3" -H "X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME:GeteBayOfficialTime" -d @postfile.txt https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll
```

Postfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GeteBayOfficialTimeRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>Your Token</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
</GeteBayOfficialTimeRequest>
```